# How can I put color on a Image link outline on html and css?

Tags: html, css

[Hello guys this my example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKdXW.png)
all of the boxes are linked, and how can i put a outline color to each of them? the image is a example of what i want to do.
Thanks in advance if who ever answer it correct :)

```
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        1st Floor Map
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <img src = "img/wetmarket.png" usemap= "#a46">
                        <map name="a46">
                            <area shape="rect" coords="19,120,95,180" alt="Sun" href="#1st_tenant" data-toggle="modal"  title = "Electric reader"  data-placement='top' class = "resetPrice">   
                        </map>
                        <!-- /.table-responsive -->
                    </div>
```

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: @Ronnel.D, show your code first

Comment: wait ill just edit it and put my code.

Comment: Please Check it i Already put the code

Comment: @jrbedard please check

Comment: @Sunny please check

Comment: post your css too!

Comment: @mlegg for now it has no css for that,

Comment: class="panel-heading" refers to css class selector   So if you have no css, where did you come up with that id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery `maphilight` plugin might be useful for what you are attempting to do.

http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/

It's designed for applying style when the imagemap links are hovered, but you might be able to make some changes to the JavaScript code if you want the "highlighting" visible all the time.